# How can I set the background color of statusbar?

Tags: ios, statusbar

I want to set a `background` color like Facebook app's `statusbar`, but I can't find a way to fix it in Apple's documents. Is there any advice for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change the status bar color, as it has not background to change.

However you could create a view on 20px height and place it behind the status bar.

If you have a UINavigationBar, you could either remove the background color of a UINavigationBar or add a subview to the UINavigationBar with a height on 20px and give it the color of the status bar.

I found this on github, you can inspect the code and find out how to change the color for the top 20px https://github.com/remirobert/RRMaterialNavigationBar

Answer (score 1):

As they say, you can generate a 20px view with the color you want.

First you'll need to hide the Status bar in the info.plist:
- Set View controller-based status bar appearance to NO

Then you can set the new color with something like this in the AppDelegate:

```
UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 20)];
view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:view];
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution consist in these two lines of code in your applicationDidFinishLaunching, in appDelegate:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = true
```

This will basically change the statusBar background color for all of your app's viewControllers, you have to set also the background color to clearColor() for all of your viewControllers.

Comment: I failed to set the color of the `keyWindow` with this method